# Retrieve each IP address of Azure web apps

Tags: powershell, azure

I want to retrieve each IP address of the on its own, because when I run the following Cmdlet:

```
$web =  (Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name forthesakeoftest).OutboundIpAddresses
```

I get the following result:
104.40.191.174,23.100.3.112,23.97.216.155,23.97.186.126,23.97.184.187
Where all the Ips are in the same line.
How can I retrieve each one of them separately?

Comment: What does `$web.GetType()` return?

Comment: It returns that base type is system.object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for your case. not exactly a beatiful solution, but it gets the job done.

```
$web =  (Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name forthesakeoftest).OutboundIpAddresses
$formattedWeb = $web.Split("{,}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`(Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name "whatever name").OutboundIpAddresses.Split(",")`

Will give you an array of IP addresses that you can then process.